# MVC Model Binding to Dictionary by Key with HTML Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, model-binding

When filtering a data list in MVC(4) I am binding several filter inputs to a dictionary that lives in the ViewModel model.

I've been able to do that with a literal declaration of the input like this (.aspx engine):

```
 <input type="text" name='Model.Filters[matchId].Filter' 
                    value='<%: Model.Filters["matchId"].Filter %>' />
```

Where "matchId" is the name of the column being filtered. The Model.Filter dictionary is defined as

```
IDictionary<string,FilterObject>
```

with FilterObject for the moment being simply:

```
[Serializable]
public class FilterObject
{
    public FilterObject()
    {
        Filter = "";
    }
    public FilterObject(String value)
    {
        Filter = value;
    }
    //[DefaultValue("")]
    public String Filter { get; set; }
}
```

So - that works as long as the Model.Filters Dictionary is initialized with all of the keys for which there Filter inputs, otherwise we naturally get a "key not found" runtime exception.

Hard-coding column-name strings into the controller is ugly and it feels like it should be possible to avoid the exception using an @Html.TextBoxFor<>(....) but I cannot find a syntax that works (or doesn't just break on invalid index object type etc.) for example:

```
Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Filters.FirstOrDefault(k=>k.Key=="matchId").Value.Filter)
```

Produces HTML of

```
  <input id="Value_Filter" name="Value.Filter" type="text" value="" />
```

which clearly does nothing useful

I'm pretty sure I'm just missing something but all the Dictionary binding examples I have found depend on Loops and binding to an int index, and I am at this point stumped, short of writing a custom Helper which seems overkill.

Any help greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: In your view, if you loop on each key value pair in your dictionary you should easily be able to get the result you're looking for.  Could you be more specific which aspect of the binding isn't working for you?

Comment: What is `matchId` and where are you getting that value from?

Comment: I have an iList of 10 columns one of which is called "matchId" - I need to filter that list by any one of those columns. I therefore have 10 (yes 10) input boxes each bound to an entry in the mentioned dictionary. 

The filter inputs, like the columns, are of various widths/data types so iterating to create those, and with them the bindings, is problematic, for layout reasons if no other.

The literally entered binding works. I just need to duplicate it with HTML.TextBoxFor or HTML.EditorFor

Hope that helps clarify :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha! I stopped fighting the tide and wrote a Helper for this, easier than I thought:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxForFilterDictionary(this HtmlHelper helper, IDictionary<string, FilterObject> filters, string fieldName, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        FilterObject filter;
        if (!filters.TryGetValue(fieldName, out filter))
        {
            filter = new FilterObject();
        }
        string nameAttribute = String.Format("Model.Filters[{0}].Filter", fieldName);
        MvcHtmlString html = helper.TextBox(nameAttribute, filter.Filter, htmlAttributes);
        return html;
    }
```

And in the HTML:

```
  <%: Html.TextBoxForFilterDictionary(Model.Filters, "matchId")%>
  <!-- a bunch of other formatting HTML -->
  <%: Html.TextBoxForFilterDictionary(Model.Filters, "matchName")%>
  <!-- and so on -->
```

My generic ViewModel now carries everything the list needs for sorting, paging, and filtering, no filter Dictionary initialization required and nary a weakly typed object in sight.

Worth the little extra effort!